# Java JNA detecting serial USB port removal

Tags: java, jna

We have a requirement to test USB enable products, where we plug/unplug the product from the PC. We are using JSSC for the serial interface.

The problem is that people tend to remove the product before closing the serial port so the Java test program hangs.

I am trying to make the Java program recognise the loss of the USB serial device and close the port for the user to prevent the issue.

I am using JNA and have the access to the DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE structure when a device is added/removed. Using pieces of code from the web I am able to see the device added/removed from the PC but my problem is dealing with the DEV_BROADCAST_PORT information.

My understanding is the structure DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE allows you to identify the kind of device, then you have to overlay the structure relevant for that device. So I have the following to allow the device type to be found:

```
                   DEV_BROADCAST_HDR bhdr = new DEV_BROADCAST_HDR(lParam.longValue());
```

I can then use bhdr.dbch_devicetype to find the DBT_DEVTYP_PORT. So I then try to use the DEV_BROADCAST_PORT by the following setup I found on the WEB.

```
                   DEV_BROADCAST_PORT bpt = new DEV_BROADCAST_PORT(bhdr.getPointer());
```

The problem is I have the ERROR 'Array fields must be initialized'. I am not sure how the cast the DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE structure to the DEV_BROADCAST_PORT structure I need using JNA.

A lot of the information on the WEB seems out of date now. I have used the code from Win32WindowDemo.java as a reference.

Any help greatly appreciated.

MPC

Comment: This looks like it's being discussed [here](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/issues/1286).  Please provide a stack trace and the relevant code causing the crash, as you may be overriding a method that causes the `force` boolean to be true.